# How to write a stress test script for asynchronous processes in python

Tags: python, django, web-applications, stress-testing, djcelery

I have a web application running on django, wherein an end user can enter a URL to process. All the processing tasks are offloaded to a celery queue which sends notification to the user when the task is completed.

I need to stress test this app with the goals.

- to determine breaking points or safe usage limits
- to confirm intended specifications are being met
- to determine modes of failure (how exactly a system fails)
- to test stable operation of a part or system outside standard usage

How do I go about writing my script in Python, given the fact that I also need to take the offloaded celery tasks into account as well.

Comment: You are talking about **asynchronous** processes?

Comment: Yes exactly. Sorry edited the question for that.

Comment: How do you notify the user?

Comment: A mail is sent when the task gets completed.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need to write your own stress testing script.

I have used www.blitz.io for stress testing. It is set up in minutes, easy to use and it makes beautiful graphs.

It has a 14 day trial so you just can test the heck out of your system for 14 days for free. This should be enough to find all your bottlenecks.

Comment: But can we put load on the offloaded celery tasks using blitz. My whole app runs as a celery task with notification being sent to the user at the ned of task completion

Comment: Also my app is behind firewall , which is why my focus was on a custom script. Is there a way in blitz to actually workaround that